# Get Percentage from SubQuery ResultSet

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Am having a requirement to show the percentage value along with the other column values in result set.

**SQl**

```
select Name, days from table
```

O/P result set

```
Name  days
Sam   20
ram   30
```

My required o\p is

```
Name  days Percentage
 Sam   20  40
 ram   30  60
```

So i modified my query as below

```
select Name, days, (days / sum(days)) as Percentage
from (select Name, days from table) as temp
```

But able to get the desired o/p.
Thanks in advance

Comment: the query will not create any performance issue. Since join can be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @tab table (name varchar(30),[days] int)
insert into @tab
select 'Sam',   20
union all
select 'ram',   30

declare @sum int
set @sum = (select sum(days) from @tab)

select name,days ,days*100/@sum   as per
from @tab
```

output

```
name    days    per
Sam     20      40
ram     30      60
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`

```
select Name, days, days * 100 / t.sum_days as Percentage
from table
cross join (
   select sum(days) sum_days from table
) t
```

if the `days` is `int` then you should cast it first to get more accurate result: `cast(days as decimal(10,2))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use window function

```
select 
    Name, days
    , Percentage = 100.0 * days / sum(days) over ()
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an uncorrelated subquery to return the total sum of days:

```
select t1.Name, t1.days, 100 * t1.days / (select sum(t2.days) from table t2) as Percentage
from table t1
```